# Send Byte array plus String over socket Java server to c++ client

Tags: java

I am new to java and writing the code the java server to communicate with c++ client
The server will read the message from the client and respond correspondingly in the same format.
The message will be in format :
The following example shows the encoding of a 385-byte message. Note that the total number of bytes transmitted is 389 `(4 byte length + message body)`.

> 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x81 |            [Message Content] Message Length (4
>   Bytes) |     Message Body (385 Bytes)

The client is written in C++ and server is in java.

Although java server is able to read the message from the client but unable to send to response in the correct format due to which client unable to communication fail between them.

JAVA Code:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (server.getInputStream());
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream(),true,"UTF-8");


while((incummsg = in.readLine()) != null && !incummsg.equals(".")) {
  mtype=sample_server.mType(incummsg);
  System.out.println("\nGateway msg:"+incummsg);
  if(sample_server.MsgMapping.get(mtype)!=null){
      reqmsgtosent=sample_server.getRequiredMsg(incummsg, mtype);
      msglen=reqmsgtosent.length();
      System.out.println("\nMsg_len:"+msglen);
      int htnolmsglen = sample_server.htonl(msglen);
      out.println(String.format("%08x",msglen)+reqmsgtosent);
      }
}
```

Thanks @xeed for th ehelp but it is still not working for me. I have a code in python which is working fine for me. I wanted to rewrite it in java but unable to do so. Python Code:

```
def SendMsg(self, msg):

    htonlMsgLen = socket.htonl(len(msg))

    htonlMsgLen32 = pack('L', htonlMsgLen)

    lenofSentMsg = self.request.send(htonlMsgLen32)

    lenofSentMsg = self.request.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
```

this is the function whihc is working fine and above written is mine which is not working in java. I tried your suggestion too but unable to make do it. May this python code help you understand my problem in better way.

Comment: You can't possibly answer this question with the code you supplied. I guess your reqmsgtosent is a String. A char has 2 bytes in java. This is the first problem, which can occure. You really should use some ByteBuffer to encode your message properly.

Comment: @xeed, You mean i have to convert all my message into Byte. I tried that also:                                                                                            byte[] breqmsgtosent = (String.format("%08x",msglen)+reqmsgtosent).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));                                                                                             and  used DataOutputStream to send the message to client but failed to so.

Comment: Well. Lets start at your String.format("%08x",msglen). This is not sending the 4 bytes of the ?int?. It is converting each digit to a character, so you get 8 or even 16 bytes. Use a ByteBuffer to convert integers to bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i kept you waiting. Its been a while and I needed to check in on that myself. Im thinking that you are properly decoding an integer consisting of 4 bytes at c++ end.
Then this should work:

```
String msg = "Hello World!";
ByteBuffer bytebuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(msg.getBytes().length+Integer.SIZE/8);
bytebuffer.putInt(msg.getBytes().length);
bytebuffer.put(msg.getBytes());
server.getOutputStream().write(bytebuffer.array());
```

But I'm almost certain that there is a better way. I believe there is a method, which combines the put functionality of the ByteBuffer and the OutputStream functionality.

Edit: A little alteration. I digged this up in an old source of mine:

```
String data = "Hello World!";
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.putInt(data.length());
mSocketSend.getOutputStream().write(b.array());
final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(mSocketSend.getOutputStream(),false);
pw.print(data);
pw.flush();
```

Keep the following in mind. To get this to work the c++ side, needs to read 4 bytes of data from the socket. Reverse the byte order, since java uses big endian, which is the network byteorder and c++ uses little endian. and use this as an integer. It would be best to interpret it as a signed integer, but it should be no problem, if it is interpreted as unsigned.

another Edit:
Just to make sure, you are not waiting for a long(8 bytes), try

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
b.putLong(data.length());
```

Comment: This should work. There are three things, you may need to take care of:
- Java works in network byte order (so you dont need to change it)
- You could possibly be decoding unsigned integers, which should not matter in this dimension
- The String encoding might be wrong, but the utf-8 and ascii encoding is the same for these characters anyways.

You need to show us the c++ side, to give you a solution

Comment: I tried your code but at the client end, it is showing length as zero and not processing further message.                                                                                           I do not have the C++ code right now. it is an old library implemented 8 years back. This is the reason I shared the python code with you which is working fine. is it of no help for you?

Comment: Well, i'm not great at python. But the second line htonlMsgLen32 = pack('L', htonlMsgLen) made me wonder, if you are using a long instead o and integer. Have you tried the putLong part?

Comment: I tried the latest code advised by you but still zero length is going at the C++ client side.                                                                                              We can achieve htonl by using below code:                                                                 ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(x).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).getInt(0);

Comment: and for htonlMsgLen32 , it is just converting it into hexdecimal.                                      In short after using both the function, we are converting integer value into hexadecimal value.e.g. for 282, it will be \x00 \x00 \x01 \x1a                                                                          and in the first send if you see in the python code, it is sending this hexadecimal value and in the second one it is sending string with "UTF-8"

Comment: As I have mentioned. Java is using network (big endian) byte order anyways. You don't need to encode the java byte order, if you are properly decoding on c++ end. Another thought: If your client decodes a message length of zero, he has to receive 0x00 00 00 00, which is the only 4 byte value interpreted as 0. If you were sending a long at this point, this is possible. If you were sending an int, the c end is expecting sth. smaller (short).

Comment: I am using below code, which is sending 4 bytes:                                                                             ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.putInt(data.length());
mSocketSend.getOutputStream().write(b.array());                                                             at client end it is showing zero length received.

Comment: then try out b.putShort(). It should never show zero, if you are using the right datatype and the value you are sending is not zero.

Comment: b.putShort((short)msg.length());                                                                                              Is it fine. Will it take the right value?

Comment: yes. keep in mind, that you need to change ByteBuffer.allocate(4) to ByteBuffer.allocate(2), too.

Comment: Why we have to allocate 2 bytes because we have to send 4 bytes.

Comment: Im just trying to remove any doubt, that the c side expects anything else than 4 bytes. If the c side says the received value is zero, it has received only 0x00 bytes. This can only be the case, if you are actually sending 0 with b.putInt(0). Or the c side expects two bytes. and what you are sending is sth like this: b.putInt(5) -> 0x00 00 00 05. And your c side is just using the first 2 bytes (short) 0x00 00. I hope you understand, what im saying.

Comment: Tried but still getting zero length at the C++ client side.

Comment: Alright. There are 2 byteorders and 3 datatypes (if we leave out a single byte). Just try out all of them. Check out my edited answer.

Comment: I tried ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);                                                                  But not working for me.                                                                                                One thing I would like to say thank you so much for your help. Giving your valuable time to me.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't go for `XML`? You can send and receive any type of data to any platform ! I think [**this**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/XMLbasedmessage.htm) and [**this**](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/java-and-c-socket-communication/222900697) would be the BEST approach for cross platform communication.

**Edit**

If you cannot go for `XML` then you can use `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. By using this you can send/receive Objects. This make your life easier.

Comment: I cannot go for xml as one cannot change the client side. the requirement is to implement the server in java.

Comment: Hi Junaid,  my problem is the client application is in C++ and must be having structure at its end. So, i have to send 4 Bytes(containing length of the rest of the message) + message in string of the length defined in 4 Bytes. is there any way i can do it in one go in my send message on socket.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, that its not really clear, what data your c side is expecting. So try out every reasonably possibility. Just to make sth. clear: There are two ByteOrders: Little Endian and Big Endian. Java uses always Big Endian. The Networking standard is Big Endian. C uses the native ByteOrder (depending on the system). On normal machines this should be Little Endian. 
If your c side does no decoding or sth. You need to convert the java byteorder manually to little endian. Infact that is what your python code does. You should be able to use ByteOrder.native() instead. Just check if the values of LITTLE_ENDIAN and native() are the same.

```
//Short
short slength = (short)length
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
b.putShort(slength);

ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
b.putShort(slength);

//Int
int ilength = (int) length
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
b.putInt(ilength);

//This is the one, which should work, if everything you say is true
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
b.putInt(ilength);

 //Long
long llength = (long) length;
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
b.putLong(llength);

ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
b.putLong(llength);
```

Comment: Hi xeed, sorry for the late reply....the suggested solution by you is not working for me....

Comment: @xeed..to get more clarity on the problem...I have written a C++ client and try to communicate it with Java server....but Java server is unable to understand the message sent by C++ client...but Java client things are working fine.....i have posted my question on a different thread....If you get the time then could you please check it...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985324/c-client-unable-to-communicate-with-java-server