# C++ Client unable to communicate with Java server

Tags: java, c++

I have written the client in Java is able to communicate with the server in Java. C++ Client is not working with server written in java. Can someone please help me to resolve this problem. I have provided the code of all the 3(Java server, Java Client, C++ Client)

C++ Client:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include<string>



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   WSAData version;        //We need to check the version.
    WORD mkword=MAKEWORD(2,2);
    int what=WSAStartup(mkword,&version);
    if(what!=0){
    std::cout<<"This version is not supported! - \n"<<WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
    }
    else{
    std::cout<<"Good - Everything fine!\n"<<std::endl;
    }

    SOCKET u_sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(u_sock==INVALID_SOCKET)
    std::cout<<"Creating socket fail\n";

    else
    std::cout<<"It was okay to create the socket\n";

    //Socket address information
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.45.88");
    addr.sin_port=htons(15000);
    std::cout<<"Successfully provided the address"<<std::endl;    
    /*==========Addressing finished==========*/

    //Now we connect
    int conn=connect(u_sock,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
    std::cout<<"conn value:"<<conn<<std::endl;
    if(conn==SOCKET_ERROR){
    std::cout<<"Error - when connecting "<<WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
    closesocket(u_sock);
    WSACleanup();
    }
     std::cout<<"Successfully connected to server"<<std::endl;

     //Send some message to remote host
    char* mymsg="Hello Server...How are you?";
    char vect[512]={0};

    int smsg=send(u_sock,mymsg,sizeof(mymsg),0);
    if(smsg==SOCKET_ERROR){
    std::cout<<"Error: "<<WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
    WSACleanup();
    }

    int get=recv(u_sock,vect,512,0);
    if(get==SOCKET_ERROR){
    std::cout<<"Error in Receiving: "<<WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<vect<<std::endl;
    closesocket(u_sock);

    getch();

    return 0;

}
```

Java Server:

```
import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;



public class EchoServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



       /* if (args.length != 1) {

        System.err.println("Usage: java EchoServer <port number>");

        System.exit(1);

    }*/

    int portNumber = 15000;

    try (

        ServerSocket serverSocket =  new ServerSocket(portNumber);

        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();     

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);                   

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    ) {

        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        out.println(inputLine);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "

        + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    }

}
```

Java Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    if (args.length != 0) {
        System.err.println(
        "Usage: java EchoClient <host name> <port number>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String hostName = "192.168.45.88";
    int portNumber = 15000;

    try (
        Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        PrintWriter out =
        new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in =
        new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn =
        new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(System.in))
    ) {
        String userInput;
        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
        hostName);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errormessages? Stacktraces?

Comment: You are sending the size of the transmission wrong. You'r `sizeof(mymsg)` is giving you the size of the character pointer, not the size of the message it points to. You need an array: `char mymsg [] = "Hello Server...How are you?";`. Also you don't send an `end-of-line` to terminate your message. Thirdly IIRC Java uses UTF16 and you are sending ASCII, you may need to use allow for that.

Comment: @Fidor...as such there is no error message. The problem is C++ client is sending the message but java Server is not receiving it or i will say unable to understand the message......

Comment: @Erik , there is no crash as such..the problem is server unable to understand what client is ending due to which server is not sending anything and client keep on waiting...

Comment: @Galik...this is the format in C++ in sending message but i need to check the UTF16 point. Could you please help me in this regard...

Comment: Erik didn't mention a crash.  He's saying use a network monitoring tool such as Wireshark to see what's going on.  Also, debug your code to see what's happening; how far you're getting, what's being sent/received etc.  Rather than "here's my code; it's not working".

Comment: The problem is resolved now....could you please help me further....if I want to send a structure of 4 Bytes + string.....then how to do it at both end....I mean C++ Client will send the this structure and java server will also send in the same manner....as we do not have structure in java ..how to handle this scenario...

Comment: Be careful when serializing/de-serializing data over the net. You need to be aware of issues such as endianness, struct padding etc. One way is to send xml (and use a schema to check the format), or use json. Another is brute-force:ing it yourself, binary send and marshalling/unmarshalling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I'll put some effort into this. Kind of a refreshing thing to do. ^^
I modified your code, so the message length pattern is used. The c client sends a message to the server, the java client decodes it and sends it back to the client. So you have both direction of encoding up and running. Please try to understand, what is happening in the code, otherwise you will run into problems again. The ByteOrder Stuff is completly done on the java side, so you can fiddle around with your closed C server.

C Client:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    WSAData version;        //We need to check the version.
    WORD mkword=MAKEWORD(2,2);
    int what=WSAStartup(mkword,&version);
    if(what!=0){
    std::cout<<"This version is not supported! - \n"<<WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
    }
    else{
    std::cout<<"Good - Everything fine!\n"<<std::endl;
    }

    SOCKET u_sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(u_sock==INVALID_SOCKET)
    std::cout<<"Creating socket fail\n";

    else
    std::cout<<"It was okay to create the socket\n";

    //Socket address information
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_port=htons(15000);
    std::cout<<"Successfully provided the address"<<std::endl;    
    /*==========Addressing finished==========*/

    //Now we connect
    int conn=connect(u_sock,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
    std::cout<<"conn value:"<<conn<<std::endl;
    if(conn==SOCKET_ERROR){
    std::cout<<"Error - when connecting "<<WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
    closesocket(u_sock);
    WSACleanup();
    }
     std::cout<<"Successfully connected to server"<<std::endl;

     //Send some message to remote host
    char* mymsg="Hello Server...How are you?";
    int length = strlen(mymsg);
    //Cast the integer to char and send it
    int smsg=send(u_sock,reinterpret_cast<char*>(&length), sizeof(int),0);
    //Send the actual message
    smsg=send(u_sock,mymsg,strlen(mymsg),0);


    int newlength;
    //Receive exactly 4 bytes for the length. If not the right length is received, repeat.
    int get = 0;
    while((get+=recv(u_sock,(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&newlength))+get,4,0)) < 4) {}
    std::cout<<"Length: " << newlength << std::endl;
    //Create new char array with newlength + 1 so we have a zero terminated string.
    char* newMsg = new char[newlength+1];
    memset(newMsg,0,newlength+1);
    get = 0;
    //Receive the string. If not the right length is received, repeat.
    while((get+=recv(u_sock,newMsg+get,newlength,0)) < newlength) {}
    std::cout<<"Message: " << newMsg << std::endl;

    closesocket(u_sock);


    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

Java Server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.#     
        int portNumber = 15000;

        try (

            ServerSocket serverSocket =  new ServerSocket(portNumber);

            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();     


            OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(os, true);               
            //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();

        ) {

            //RECV
            //Create ByteBuffer for length integer
            ByteBuffer bLength = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
            //C is usually Little_Endian
            bLength.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            //Read 4 bytes
            is.read(bLength.array(), 0, 4);
            //Convert the length
            int length = bLength.getInt();
            System.out.println("Length: "+length);


            //Allocate ByteBuffer for message
            ByteBuffer bMessage = ByteBuffer.allocate(length);
            bMessage.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            is.read(bMessage.array(), 0, length);
            //Convert the message to string
            String msg = new String( bMessage.array() );
            System.out.println(msg);


            //SEND
            //Create ByteBuffer with length
            ByteBuffer bLengthNew = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
            bLengthNew.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            bLengthNew.putInt(msg.length());

            //Write the length bytebuffer to the outputstream
            os.write(bLengthNew.array());

            //Write the message to the outputstream. (Don't use println)
            out.print(msg);
            //Flush it. (It automatically gets flushed on a \n, but we dont want that.
            out.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port "

            + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }



    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot xeed, it is working fine for me....made a small change...instead of LITTLE_ENDIAN using BIG_ENDIAN.....just one more thing.....if I have to put in a loop all this so that it keeps one reading and responding for all the messages then what condition should be used...as second time it fails to get the length right....                                                length = bLength.getInt();                                                                                                may i know what wrong i am doing.....

Comment: If the length you have received is correct, you should be able to loop all of the receiving part and receive message after message. If you have just looped the part from //RECV to //SEND, there is a problem on the sending side. Maybe the message sent has not the length you received.Maybe the looping on the other side is incorrect.

Comment: First time it is picking the message correctly...but second time..it is not picking and saying Length = 0 and fails after that.....Anything which I am still missing ...any check which is not there....

Comment: I can't tell. There is definetly an error in your code. As I said you need to understand how this works, and what it actually means, what we are talking about. ByteOrder, Zero terminated strings, Character encoding, bit & byte representation of variables.

Answer (score 1):

Few things :

1) when sending data with winsock sockets, sizeof (mymsg) is wrong, it should be strlen (mymsg)+1

2) I have written a Java-Server-C++ -Client before , and the main thing is dealing with ASCII vs. UNICODE. in the Java side receiving  , make sure it builds the string from ASCII character as encoding. on the other hand , when sending data to winsock server - send it as binary data , otherwise the winsock server won't be able to finish recv() function .

Comment: what he said. Additionally you would want to add a "\n" at the end at your c client string, because you are reading whole line in your java server.

Comment: @David....I tried with 1)strlen not working for me...the error which i have noticed in debug mode is that  "unable to evaluate the inputline"...could you please check where I am wrong in Java server......                                                  2)I am knew to Java...Could you please suggest what exactly i have to do to take care of ASCII vs UNICODE.....

Comment: did you add '\n' as we suggested?

Comment: It has started working for me....Thanks for your help... 2 problems were there 1)use strlen(mymsg) instead mymsg,sizeof(mymsg) 2) adding '\n' in the end of the message.....

Comment: @David..could you please help me now....if I want to send a structure of 4 Bytes + string.....then how to do it at both end....I mean C++ Client will send the this structure and java server will also send in the same manner....as we do not have structure in java ..how to handle this scenario...

Comment: open different question on it. but the answer will probably the use of JSON

Comment: @David...it is already a open question....but still looking for the answer....the only problem is I do not have the C++ source code for it....this is the reason i created a sample code of C++ to communicate with Java..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982672/send-byte-array-plus-string-over-socket-java-server-to-c-client